# jQuery: If error exists remove old one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I use a small Ajax request for my contact form for showing my validation.

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send-mail',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // Success...

            $("#validation-output-success").text("Success!");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Error...

            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

            $.each(errors, function( k, v ) {
                $("#validation-output-error").text( v ).append('<br />');
            });

        }
    });
});
```

It works fine, when there is something empty it will return it and says what input is empty. And same goes for if it works, output will be success!

But now comes the problem, when there is a field empty he will output it, but when you push another time on the submit button he will give the same error but don't remove the old error. So you will get the same error message double.

And then if you complete it, he will return success. But he will still show the old error messages.

My question is, how can I use the .fadeOut(), .remove() or another jquery function to remove the old error(s) when you submit the form again.

Comment: Can't you just add this in your submit event? `$("#validation-output-error").hide();` or just clear the text `$("#validation-output-error").text("");`

Comment: The way you output the errors is bad if there will be more than one.

Comment: yes I can use that, and the old error message will go away. But because of the hide, he will remove completely. So if you first get an error message, the succes message will hide, but if you solve the error message, he will not show you the success message. Same goes for the reverse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can empty the error text and `fadeOut()` out on submit. Then add `fadeIn()` to the success/error messages. Something like:

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     $("#validation-output-error").text("").fadeOut();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send-mail',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // Success...

            $("#validation-output-success").text("Success!").fadeIn();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Error...

            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

            $.each(errors, function( k, v ) {
                $("#validation-output-error").text( v ).append('<br />').fadeIn();
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Also, if you haven't already done so, you may want to give the error/success messages `display: none;` in the css.

Comment: Thanks @dwreck08 it works great now! The error message will be removed now every time you click on the button.

Comment: do you also know how to display multiple errors in a .text function? Because now it will only show one error, also if there are more than one error. I know with a createTextNote that you can show multiple errors, but then the old errors will also be showed.